# Can't get array item to filter out in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

React newb here. Basically I am simply trying to remove an array item with the `handleRemove` function onClick. Seems like standard procedure and most of what I've read in articles is doing something near identical in my eyes.

I've messed around with it a ton and at one point had it deleting the item, but then it wouldn't rerender, and I eventually ended up where I started. Also tried putting the handler on both li and span, but neither worked. I also have more data, but I removed some of it for space sake. I also have a category openguard as well.

```
function Technique() {

  const [list, setList] = React.useState([
    {
      closedguard: [
        {
          name: "Armbar",
          link: "",
          x: "X",
          id: "1",
        },
        {
          name: "Triangle",
          link: "",
          x: "X",
          id: "2",
        },
        {
          name: "Omaplata",
          link: "",
          x: "X",
          id: "3",
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);

  const handleRemove = (id) => {
    const newList = list.filter(move => move.id !== id);
    setList(newList);
  };

  return (
    <div className="guard">
      <span onClick={(e) => toggleSubMenu(e, 0)}>
        <AddCircleIcon style={{ position: "relative", top: "26" }} />
      </span>{" "}
      
      <ul className="techUl">
        {" "}
        Closed Guard
        {list.map((pos) =>pos.closedguard.map((move, id) => (
          <li
            onClick={() => handleRemove(id)}
            key={id}
            className="techLi"              
          >{move.name}<span > {move.x}</span>    
          </li>        
          ))
        )}
      </ul>  
    </div>
  );
}

export default Technique;
```

Comment: you probably want to pass move.id to handleRemove instead of id, unless the array index is the same as move.id

Comment: This and the comment below got it working , thank you for the time.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this.

```
const handleRemove = (id) => {
    const newList = list[0].closedguard.filter(move => move.id !== id);
    setList([{ closedguard: newList }]);
};
```

You use `list` variable wrong too.
The parameter after item on array map function is index of item. It is not id.
Please use like this.

```
{list.map((pos) =>pos.closedguard.map((move, index) => (
  <li
    onClick={() => handleRemove(move.id)}
    key={move.id}
    className="techLi"              
  >{move.name}<span > {move.x}</span>    
  </li>        
  ))
)}
```

Comment: Thanks but this gave me this error on click
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.
```

Comment: Got it working by using this and adjusting a removing a troublesome function not listed, thanks.